# C# Sort data table descending by a few columns when there is empty cells

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have table with tow (int) columns: `countSelected` and `globalCount`. I want to sort the table descending by `countSelected` first and then descending by `globalSelected`.
I tried:

```
DataTable dt = myTable;
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    dt = dt.AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(x => x.Field<int>("countSelected")).ThenByDescending(x => x.Field<int>("GlobalCount"))
           .Select(x => x)
           .CopyToDataTable();
}
```

but it's `bad:"System.InvalidCastException"`. Maybe because a few cells are empty.
How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Are you sure about the data type? Try to add "?" after int. You can check for DBNull.value too.

Comment: Did you try simple casting like "Int.Parse(x.countSelected)"?

Comment: If your DataTable is used as DataSource for some Controls: `myTable.DefaultView.Sort = "countSelected DESC, GlobalCount DESC";`. Controls use the DataTable.DefaultView as the source of data, so the data will be presented as sorted (while the DataTable's Rows order is untouched). If not bound and you want to generate a new DataTable, then `Sort` and `var dt = myTable.DefaultView.ToTable();`. If your DataTable is bound, I suggest to use a BindingSource as the DataSource *mediator* object and use its Sort method to sort the data.

Comment: Thank you! I success with your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Is it correct that the two columns have different casing styles? And you are sure that they are nullable 32-bit integers?

Then try this:

```
DataTable dt = myTable;
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    dt = dt.AsEnumerable()
           .OrderByDescending(x => x.Field<int?>("countSelected"))
           .ThenByDescending(x => x.Field<int?>("GlobalCount"))
           .Select(x => x)
           .CopyToDataTable();
}
```